# 3D Plot of .txt File of the Surface Plotting Variety

Tags: plotting, import, data-format

I'm having a bit of trouble. I've seen other questions answered on here about how to 3D plot data from .txt files of the format:

```
x y z

x y z

x y z
```

Which works well with the `ListPointPlot` function. However, using that methodology seems to confuse poor *Mathematica* when trying to do surface plotting of data that is in the format

```
` y y y y y y y y y y y y y y

z x x x x x x x x x x x x x x

z x x x x x x x x x x x x x x

z x x x x x x x x x x x x x x
```

Where the ` is a place holder (just an empty space in my case). I've tried the manipulations that I know of or could find around the web, but those attempts end with errors being kicked back at me.

How would I get *Mathematica* to plot this .txt data?

Comment: Please include a proper minimal example that is indicative of your .txt file. As written, it is not clear how one would identify the different `x`s on each line. (I'm assuming they're different x's corresponding to the y's on top)

Comment: If the $y$'s and $z$'s are uniformly spaced, you can try [`ListPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListPlot3D.html) on the array of $x$'s. Use the `DataRange` option to specify the range of $y$ and $z$.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably read in the text file by importing it as a "Table":

```
d = ImportString["0 1 2 3\n4 2 1 0\n5 1 0 1\n6 0 1 2", "Table"]

0   1   2   3
4   2   1   0
5   1   0   1
6   0   1   2
```

Here I've used `ImportString` rather than `Import` (so I can use a string rather than a file).

Then you could split the values off:

```
x = Rest /@ Rest @ d;
y = Rest @ First @ d;
z = First /@ Rest @ d;
```

And reconstitute them in a list of `{x, y, z}` triples:

```
MapThread[Prepend, {Outer[List, y, z], x}, 2] ~Flatten~ 1
```

Comment: Let's say my file is relatively massive, though. As in, I'd be looking for a way to do this without manually typing in every number initially.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear in the answer.  `Import["C:\\yourfile.dat", "Table"]` will read the file directly.  I just used `ImportString` as a toy example.